# Serenity/Cucumber test are not running because of a java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: cucumber.runner.TimeServiceEventBus

Tags: java, cucumber, serenity-bdd, cucumber-serenity

When I run my Serenity BDD tests from commandline I get the following stacktrace:

```
initializationError(net.persgroep.targetqa.webTests.WebTest)  Time elapsed: 0.002 s  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: cucumber/runner/TimeServiceEventBus
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: cucumber.runner.TimeServiceEventBus
```

On the Serenity chat they suggested that I changed my dependency versions. So I did that but still I've got the error.

These are my dependencies in my pom file:

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
        <artifactId>serenity-core</artifactId>
        <version>${serenity.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
                <artifactId>cucumber-core</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
        <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
        <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
        <artifactId>serenity-junit</artifactId>
        <version>${serenity.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
        <artifactId>serenity-screenplay</artifactId>
        <version>${serenity.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
        <artifactId>serenity-screenplay-webdriver</artifactId>
        <version>${serenity.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>



    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
        <artifactId>serenity-model</artifactId>
        <version>${serenity.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
        <artifactId>serenity-cucumber</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.48</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
        <artifactId>serenity-core</artifactId>
        <version>${serenity.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

The versions :

```
 <serenity.version>2.0.89</serenity.version>
        <serenity.maven.version>2.0.89</serenity.maven.version>
        <serenity.cucumber.version>1.9.48</serenity.cucumber.version>
        <cucumber.version>4.8.0</cucumber.version>
```

It used to work before, some team members suggested I should using declarative programming, so we changed a few for loops and I wanted to check if the test were still running.
Thats when I got this error.

Comment: This looks like it might be a clash in dependencies/versions. Afaik Cucumber dependencies are provided by Serenity, so I'd suggest removing the explicit Cucumber dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

First you have an exclusion for:

```
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-core</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
```

which *should* explain the "ClassNotFoundException: cucumber.runner.TimeServiceEventBus" error.

Further you have duplicate dependencies. You should really investigate all the warnings that Maven is giving you. And lastly, you are forcing *possibly* incompatible pieces of Serenity onto itself, by explicitly declaring individual bits of Serenity. Unless you have a particularly good reason for this, you should really avoid that!

In any case, the **one** simple dependency:

```
            <dependency>
                    <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
                    <artifactId>serenity-cucumber</artifactId>
                    <version>${serenity.version}</version>
            </dependency>
```

brings in **everything** you will need: all of Cucumber, all of Selenium, JUnit, and of course all of Serenity.

You can also use:

```
            <dependency>
                    <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
                    <artifactId>serenity-cucumber4</artifactId>
                    <version>${serenity.version}</version>
            </dependency>
```

note the extra **4** there, if you want to use Cucumber version 4. Although last time I checked (admittedly it has been a while), this was still experimental.

See `mvn dependency:tree` to make sure.